# How to use files created during build stage with dockerfile in the same stage?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I'm practicing with Gitlab CI to understand how to build an application and then use that within a Docker image. For now, my repo consists simply of helloworld.txt, dockerfile, and gitlab-ci.yml.

PROBLEM: During the build stage, I use a shell executor to 'zip helloworld.zip helloworld.txt". Then, I "docker build -t myproject/myapp ." where I expect to COPY helloworld.zip /" but it seems that the zip file I created is not available during the docker build context. Am I not saving the helloworld.zip file to the right location? Or something else? My long term intent is to write a python application, and during the build stage to compile into a single executable and copy into a docker container.

```
#cat helloworld.txt
hello world

#cat dockerfile
FROM centos:7
COPY helloworld.zip /
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

#cat gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
    - build
    - test
    - release
    - deploy

variables:
  IMAGE_TEST_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

before_script:
  - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "compile the program"
    - zip zipfile.zip helloworld.txt 
    - docker build --pull -t $IMAGE_TEST_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TEST_NAME

test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TEST_NAME
    - docker run $IMAGE_TEST_NAME yum install unzip -y && unzip /helloworld.zip && cat /helloworld.txt

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TEST_NAME
    - docker tag $IMAGE_TEST_NAME $IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME
    - docker push $IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME
  only:
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
```

I expect that within the same stage (in this case build), I can run a program such as zip and then COPY that zip file into a given directory within a newly built docker image during the docker build process.

**EDIT**

After learning that I can't do this, I've created two different stages: build_app and build_container. Also knowing that artifacts are used by default in following stages, I didn't add an artifacts to the first stage or a dependancies to the next stage. This is the gitlab-ci.yml below and is still producing the same error.

```
stages:
    - build_app
    - build_container
    - test
    - release
    - deploy

# you can delete this line if you're not using Docker
#image: centos:latest
variables:
  IMAGE_TEST_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

before_script:
  - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin

build_app:
  stage: build_app
  script:
    - echo "compile the program"
    - zip zipfile.zip helloworld.txt 

build_container:
  stage: build_container
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $IMAGE_TEST_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TEST_NAME

test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TEST_NAME
    - docker run $IMAGE_TEST_NAME yum install unzip -y && unzip /helloworld.zip && cat /helloworld.txt

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TEST_NAME
    - docker tag $IMAGE_TEST_NAME $IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME
    - docker push $IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME
  only:
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
```

Job Status:
Build App: Passed
Build Container: Failed

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.6.1 (8d829975)
  on gitrunner-shell trtHcQTS
Using Shell executor...
Running on gitrunner.example.com...
Fetching changes...
Removing zipfile.zip
HEAD is now at e0a0a95 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
Checking out e0a0a952 as newFeature...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
$ docker build --pull -t $IMAGE_TEST_NAME .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  112.1kB

Step 1/3 : FROM centos:7
7: Pulling from library/centos
Digest: sha256:184e5f35598e333bfa7de10d8fb1cebb5ee4df5bc0f970bf2b1e7c7345136426
Status: Image is up to date for centos:7
 ---> 1e1148e4cc2c
Step 2/3 : COPY helloworld.zip /
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder312764301/helloworld.zip: no such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Gitlab CI's job model assumes that jobs of the same stage are independent.

See the [manual](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies%5D) for the `dependencies` keyword in `gitlab-ci.yml`:

> This feature [...] allows you to define the artifacts to pass between different jobs.
>
> Note that artifacts from all previous stages are passed by default.
>
> [...] You can only define jobs from stages that are executed before the current one.

Comment: Thanks. I created two different stages: build_app and build_container. Knowing that artifacts are used in the next stage by default, I'm still getting same error that helloworld.zip cannot be found during the docker build.

Comment: In `build_app` `zipfile.zip` is created, while in `build_container` `helloworld.zip` is accessed.

Comment: I think I'm having an issuing accessing helloworld.zip during the build_container stage. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314886/why-does-gitlab-ci-remove-artifact-during-next-stage