# Why does Gitlab-CI remove artifact during next stage?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

After having specified dependencies, `Gitlab-CI` still removes the artifact from the working directory when entering the next stage. I've tried all different variations of this code which I think should work but have been unsuccessful. Additionally, I've been reading up on this for hours with no success yet.

Gitlab 11.6.0

```
stages:
    - build_app
    - build_container
    - test
    - release
    - deploy

variables:
  IMAGE_TEST_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

build_app:
  stage: build_app
  script:
    - echo "compile the program"
    - zip zipfile.zip helloworld.txt 
    - pwd
    - ls -al
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /zip

build_container:
  stage: build_container
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
  dependencies:
    - build_app
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls -al
    - docker build --pull -t $IMAGE_TEST_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TEST_NAME

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
  script: 
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TEST_NAME
    - docker run $IMAGE_TEST_NAME yum install unzip -y && unzip /helloworld.zip && cat /helloworld.txt

release:
  stage: release
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
  script:
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TEST_NAME
    - docker tag $IMAGE_TEST_NAME $IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME
    - docker push $IMAGE_RELEASE_NAME
  only:
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
```

Error from `build_container` stage:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.6.1 (8d829975)
  on gitrunner-shell trtHcQTS
Using Shell executor...
Running on gitrunner.example.com...
Fetching changes...
Removing zipfile.zip #################### <------------- this right here
HEAD is now at 07e787e Update .gitlab-ci.yml
Checking out 07e787ec as newFeature...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
$ pwd
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/trtHcQTS/0/dhealy/docker-helloworld-test
$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   80 Jan 22 12:10 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   70 Jan 21 17:48 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   57 Jan 22 12:10 dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x 5 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  138 Jan 22 12:10 .git
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 1450 Jan 22 12:10 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   11 Jan 22 12:10 helloworld.txt
$ docker build --pull -t $IMAGE_TEST_NAME .
Sending build context to Docker daemon    151kB

Step 1/3 : FROM centos:7
7: Pulling from library/centos
Digest: sha256:184e5f35598e333bfa7de10d8fb1cebb5ee4df5bc0f970bf2b1e7c7345136426
Status: Image is up to date for centos:7
 ---> 1e1148e4cc2c
Step 2/3 : COPY zip/helloworld.zip /
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder929937870/zip/helloworld.zip: no such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I'm expecting that `helloworld.zip` will existing in the working directory during the next stage, `build_container`.

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly normal that your zip file is removed because at the start of every jobs the sources are synchronized with the current commit.

Your problem come from the artifact path of your zip file which is incorrect in build_app job. You should write:

```
artifacts:
  paths:
  - zipfile.zip
```